# Can't Read the latest Messages from kafka topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I am using Spotify docker version of the Kafka.
I am having right now a single producer and one broker and one single consumer.

The problem is that with this configuration I am unable to get the latest messages from the Kafka. 
If I default to `auto_offset_reset='earliest'` then I am getting all the messages.

Here is my code for the consumer which is not printing any message from the Kafka even when there are new messages there.

```
def consumer():
consumer = KafkaConsumer('stories',
                         enable_auto_commit=False,
                         value_deserializer=lambda m: json.loads(m.decode('ascii')),
                         bootstrap_servers=['127.0.0.1:9092'],
                         auto_offset_reset='latest',
                         consumer_timeout_ms=1000
                         )

for message in consumer:
    # message value and key are raw bytes -- decode if necessary!
    # e.g., for unicode: `message.value.decode('utf-8')`
    print("%s:%d:%d: key=%s value=%s" % (message.topic, message.partition,
                                         message.offset, message.key,
                                         message.value))
```

Can someone help me out and let me know where is the problem?

I am just trying to get the messages which are not read by the consumer from the Kafka.

Here is the Kafka Consumer: https://hastebin.com/umuhugacez.py

Here is the Kafka Producer: https://hastebin.com/laderolawi.py

Comment: What do you mean you are unable to read the latest messages from Kafka? Are there any new messages while the consumer is running or not?

Comment: I am trying to run the consumer after the producer had been run.
I have posted the code for the both above. Please have a look and advice. Thank you.

Comment: Instead of adding a link, please put your code directly on SO.

Comment: The code was big enough with multiple files to cause the confusion. Hence used the 3rd party service. Sorry if it isn't covered under the rules.

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous: I am running this command inside my docker container `./kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic stories--from-beginning`
and at the same time, I am running the `webScrapper.py` which is my producer.
the producer is producing the messages but I don't see any output in the console of the docker

Comment: You would need to get `endOffset()` and than `seek()` to `endOffset - 1` and than `poll()` -- I refer to Java API -- but Python API should also allow to do this.

Comment: Unrelated, but last time I checked the Spotify docker container, it's several releases out of date for Kafka

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the comment. I switched to the wurstmeister/kafka-docker image. No problem thus far.

Comment: Glad to hear. Note: The Confluent images are "vendor supported" ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just an update: From Kafka 0.9 and forth, Kafka is using a new Java version of the consumer and the auto.offset.reset parameter names have changed; From the manual:

**auto_offset_reset is wrong in your code  It should be earliest.**

earliest: automatically reset the offset to the earliest offset

latest: automatically reset the offset to the latest offset

none: throw exception to the consumer if no previous offset is found for the consumer's group

anything else: throw exception to the consumer.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. No matter what the settings in consumer, it always use to buffer the data when I tried to do video streaming. My case was solved by seeking the offset to end after defining consumer. You can try adding

```
consumer.poll() 
consumer.seek_to_end()
```